# how to concatenate values from two Uitextfield into a single string in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to take two value from user i.e name and location and then want to concatenate them  into single string to produce output string

```
IBOutlet UITextField *txtName;
IBOutlet UITextField *txtLoc;
```

Want to concatenate them to produce below string.

**Student Name is txtName and He is from txtLoc**

Basically that's my complete code.

```
NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Student Name is %@  from  %@ phone Number is%@ and he want to say%", txtName.text, txtLoc.text,txtPho.text,txtBody.text];



-(void) send:(id) sender {
    [self sendEmailTo:@"naumankhattak@gmail.com" withSubject:@"Contact for Quran Focus from iphone Application" withBody:message];
```

That's what I want to do.
and em getting error

'txtName' undeclared here(not in a function)

'txtLoc' undeclared here(not in a function)
'txtPho' undeclared here(not in a function)
'txtBody' undeclared here(not in a function)

Though I have correctly declared all outlets.

Comment: @ my spellings uh God bless me... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your message assignment line inside the send: function, just before the call to sendEmailTo:withSubject:withBody:.

Answer (score 6):

```
NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Student Name is %@ and He is from %@", txtName.text, txtLoc.text];
```

Comment: only txtName.text, not just txtName

Comment: Yup, noticed that the second i posted.

Comment: Thansk i have done that but em still getting this error... "'txtName'undeclared here(not in a function)"

Comment: The syntax for concatenating is correct. However you will also need to ensure that the txtName and txtLoc variables are known to the code. Make sure you #import the header files that defines them.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *outputString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Student Name is %@ and he is from %@",txtName.text,txtLoc.text];
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the text string from each UITextField ([txtName text]) and use a stringByAppendingString method:

combinedString = [[txtName text] stringByAppendingString:[txtLoc text]]